# How do I configure the vim-perl plugin with lazy plugin manager so it runs "do" like with vim-plug?

Tags: plugins, neovim

I have this in my lua file and it works:

```
{
  "vim-perl/vim-perl",
  lazy = true,
  ft = "perl",
},
```

The [vim-perl plugin](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl?tab=readme-ov-file#installing-using-vim-plug) shows this example when using vim-plug:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'vim-perl/vim-perl', { 'for': 'perl', 'do': 'make clean carp dancer highlight-all-pragmas moose test-more try-tiny' }

call plug#end()
```

How do I implement the "do" command using lazy vim plugin manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lazy.vim`, you can add a `build` function for your plugin that is executed when a plugin is installed or updated. See `lazy.vim` [documentation](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim) for details.

```lua
{
  "vim-perl/vim-perl",
  lazy = true,
  ft = "perl",
  build = "make clean carp dancer highlight-all-pragmas moose test-more try-tiny",
},
```